# How does kernel assign ip address and nic to sockets

Tags: sockets, tap, nic, tun

When you write something like:

```
   s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
   s.connect((siteIp,80))
   s.send(...
```

How does the linux kernel know from which nic it is supposed to send the packets when no information about binding the socket is provided.

How can i for example replace this default nic with my own tun/tap interface?

Also where can i get more in depth information about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The OS uses its internal routing tables to make a best guess about which NIC has the best chance of reaching the IP you are connecting to.  Routes are associated with NICs and priorities.  If an outbound packet has a destination IP that matches a given route, the associated NIC is used.  Otherwise, a route with an appropriate priority (such as a gateway or VPN) is used, since the packet IP may be on another network reached through that route.

If you want to specify which NIC is used, you have to `bind()` before you `connect()`.

Comment: but how does a vpn route all trafiic through itself?

Comment: A VPN has an entry in the OS routing tables, just like any other NIC/adapter.